# Ionic execute a funtion every 10 minutes even after app got killed

Tags: javascript, android, ios, typescript, ionic3

I got an Ionic 3 app and need to execute a function every 10~15 minutes, I tried using timeout but it only works if the app is minimized, the background plugin seems to work just the same, there's any way to run even after the app got killed?

```
  teste_bg(){
    this._storage.get('var').then(val=>{
      let t
      console.log(val)
      t=parseInt(val)
      this.teste=t
      t+=1
      this._storage.set('var',t);
    }).catch(()=>{
      this._storage.set('var',1)
    })

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.teste_bg()
    }, 1000)
  }
```

Comment: If the app is killed, then it is dead. Even if the app is just suspended you cannot execute code at a specific interval on iOS. The available background modes for iOS are covered in the iOS application programming guide from Apple

Comment: but a lot of apps do that, facebook,whatsapp etc. how they do?

Comment: can i bind the funtion to some action?like when screen is unlocked?

Comment: @MatheusLima You might want to check out [Cordova's resume event](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/events/events.html#resume) then

Comment: @MatheusLima They don't execute timed code when they are killed. You can use strategies like push notifications to send notifications to the user from your server or perform actions when your app is relaunched by the user that updates state based on elapsed time. You are also asking about Android and iOS. I don't know about Android, so there might be additional capabilities, but on iOS you can't do this. You should explain more clearly what you actually want to do as there may be strategies that can achieve the same result

Comment: @Paulw11 how i do thata https://stackoverflow.com/q/50612004/6839517, i call the func but cant show the correct value

Comment: A background location update can act as a trigger to allow your app to execute in the background, but not if your app is terminated, only if the app is suspended. If the user terminates an app on iOS then iOS assumes the user wanted the app dead and will not relaunch it until the user taps the icon or a notification from the app.

Comment: theres anyway to do like whatsapp do with the messages?